# iframe spell check algorithm

Tags: javascript, iframe, client-side, spell-checking

I want to find the best way (using javascript) to check the spelling of an iframe content based on the results that will be returned by the 'hunspell' spell checker.

- scan fast word by word the iframe content
- add a red underline style for each misspelled word that would work fast for the entire iframe content
- remove the spans when the user disabled spelling, etc

Comment: Are the documents that are to be spell-checked on the same domain as the checker?

Comment: The iframe it's hosted in a WinForms application so yes, same domain.